# how i make the LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 in the directX12?

Tags: directx, directx-9, directx-12

how do I LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 in directX12?
for some reason I need to update my directX to 12
and i need to update my code.
how do i do this in directX 12? LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9

`LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9`

ignore i need this to upload my post